# source code to create jira user

Tags: jira, junit4

I want to create a JIRA user using the api.
So that I can run the test case using junit. 
i.e. i am trying to update the custom field of UserCFType through junit integration test. for that I have to pass some test user.

```
issueUpdateRequest.fields(new IssueFields().customField((long) 10200,
            testUserObject));
    try {
        issueClient.edit(testIssue, issueUpdateRequest);
    } catch (java.lang.RuntimeException e) {
        assertEquals("UnableToEditError", CLEAR_ERROR, e.getMessage());
    }
```

In the above code I have to pass the JIRA user in place of the testUserObject.
how should I create some sample JIRA user object.

Thanks & Regards,
Suresh

Answer (score 1):

You can create users using the JIRA java api with [UserService](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/user/UserService.html).

- First create a [CreateUserRequest](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/user/UserService.CreateUserRequest.html).
- Then validate if it is valid using one of the [validateCreateUser](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/user/UserService.html#validateCreateUser-com.atlassian.jira.bc.user.UserService.CreateUserRequest-)
  methods.
- Then call one of the [createUser](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/user/UserService.html#createUser-com.atlassian.jira.bc.user.UserService.CreateUserValidationResult-) methods, using the [CreateUserValidationResult](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/bc/user/UserService.CreateUserValidationResult.html)
  instance returned by the validate method.